# When trying to .append() some JSX to the body, I get [object Object]...

Tags: reactjs

I have a multiple field form, and I'm trying to get a small Form Warning to display when the user inputs wrong information. The problem I'm having is that the form will not display the warning under the desired input correctly. I have been told that this is because the Form warning is positioned absolutely, and thus and parents along that way that are not-staticly-positioned will throw off the alignment.

The recommendation was to use .append or .after in componentWillMount() to put the Form Warning component in the body, so FormWarning component can be positioned absolutely to the window. Makes sense to me, but my attempts only being me an [object Object] at the very bottom of my page.

Can anyone provide any insight into why this is occurring and what I can do to fix it? I've tried multiple different ways of putting this, but nothing works. I always just get [object Object]

```
componentWillMount(){
   this.formWarningToBody();

}

formWarningToBody = () => {
  let form =[]
  form.push(<FormWarning visible={this.state.formWarning.visible} 
invalidInputID={this.state.formWarning.invalidInputID} text=
{this.state.formWarning.text}/>)
  document.body.append({form})
}

render() {
    if (this.state.isSubmitted) return <Redirect to="/order" />
    let CustomTag = this.props.labels ? 'label' : 'span',
    { inputs, saveInputVal, styles, state } = this,
    { formWarning, submitting } = state,
    { invalidInputID, text, visible } = formWarning

return (
  <div style={this.styles.formWrapper}>
    {
      typeof this.props.headerText === 'string'
        ? ( <h2 style={this.styles.formHeader}>{this.props.headerText}</h2> )
        : this.props.headerText.map((text) => {
          return <h2 key={text} style={this.styles.formHeader} className={'header'+this.props.headerText.indexOf(text)}>{text}</h2>
        })
    }
    <form onSubmit={this.submit} style={this.styles.form}>
      <FormOneInputs inputs={inputs} saveInputVal={saveInputVal} CustomTag={CustomTag} styles={styles} />
      <button style={this.styles.button}>{this.props.buttonText}</button>

    </form>
    <Throbber throbberText='Reserving your order...' showThrobber={submitting} />
  </div>
)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how React works, you can't just push JSX to DOM because a JSX element is indeed an object, which is then rendered to HTML. You can use React Portals.

See docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html